# is there any way to apply post filter in Elasticsearch on only aggregated result on on all the document?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am creating a dashboard for number of active user in my application with the help of Elasticsearch and kibana. so what i am trying to do is get the last action of every user, basically action contains login, logout, change_password of each user then if last action is login then user is active. let me know if my logic is correct.
After the query is ready i will create metric aggregator in kibana visualization to show number of active user.

Here is what i tried.

**my elasticquery**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "action.keyword": "LOGIN"
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "principal.keyword"
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Here is the response**

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "023079d8-b94c-4831-9135-0b75c6d423c2",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "023079d8-b94c-4831-9135-0b75c6d423c2",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104659807,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser_09"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "principal.keyword" : [
            "rootuser_09"
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          1587104659807
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "873816ad-7e46-4ffa-abf9-1ea5a0bcf04b",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "873816ad-7e46-4ffa-abf9-1ea5a0bcf04b",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "3000",
          "principal" : "rootuser",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104336316,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "3000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        },
        "fields" : {
          "principal.keyword" : [
            "rootuser"
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          1587104336316
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**my query is even though those users last action is LOGOUT it is returning LOGIN details i think the match query is running on whole dataset instead of aggregated result**

**below query returns the whole data in my index**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

**above query result**

```
{
  "took" : 10,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 14,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ede971d5-d284-4205-96b0-6ee4cc441d83",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "ede971d5-d284-4205-96b0-6ee4cc441d83",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104355983,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser_09"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "03d86e04-f031-4601-9ca0-cd11c0be39a0",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "03d86e04-f031-4601-9ca0-cd11c0be39a0",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : null,
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : null,
          "timestamp" : 1587104356225,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : null,
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN_FROM_SAME",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [
            {
              "key" : "DESCRIPTION",
              "value" : "NameMisamtchlog:Old user logged in from same browser:rootuser,Current user:rootuser_09",
              "timestamp" : 1587104356225
            }
          ],
          "targets" : [ ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "a283bf8f-5d98-4b73-913c-483fcc721f5d",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "a283bf8f-5d98-4b73-913c-483fcc721f5d",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : null,
          "timestamp" : 1587105465016,
          "source" : "https://localhost:8443/webconsole/menu/IDMAN",
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGOUT",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [ ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "d0ebf819-506a-493e-9b2e-a427073b038e",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "d0ebf819-506a-493e-9b2e-a427073b038e",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104270464,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser_09"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "c947ed80-2c9e-4793-83b6-ef345a3bed14",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "c947ed80-2c9e-4793-83b6-ef345a3bed14",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : null,
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : null,
          "timestamp" : 1587104270739,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : null,
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN_FROM_SAME",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [
            {
              "key" : "DESCRIPTION",
              "value" : "NameMisamtchlog:Old user logged in from same browser:rootuser,Current user:rootuser_09",
              "timestamp" : 1587104270739
            }
          ],
          "targets" : [ ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "a3a8bce5-f246-4c26-ba69-d2ca1917b650",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "a3a8bce5-f246-4c26-ba69-d2ca1917b650",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "3000",
          "principal" : "rootuser",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104280465,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "3000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "36c3d2e0-9051-4a55-a5f3-63f5874de951",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "36c3d2e0-9051-4a55-a5f3-63f5874de951",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : null,
          "principal" : "rootuser",
          "managedSysId" : null,
          "timestamp" : 1587104280744,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : null,
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN_FROM_SAME",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [
            {
              "key" : "DESCRIPTION",
              "value" : "NameMisamtchlog:Old user logged in from same browser:rootuser_09,Current user:rootuser",
              "timestamp" : 1587104280744
            }
          ],
          "targets" : [ ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "023079d8-b94c-4831-9135-0b75c6d423c2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "023079d8-b94c-4831-9135-0b75c6d423c2",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104659807,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser_09"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "873816ad-7e46-4ffa-abf9-1ea5a0bcf04b",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "873816ad-7e46-4ffa-abf9-1ea5a0bcf04b",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "3000",
          "principal" : "rootuser",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104336316,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "3000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "e9b520fc-e7e8-4cbf-9924-2ef0a05ac1c4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "e9b520fc-e7e8-4cbf-9924-2ef0a05ac1c4",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : null,
          "timestamp" : 1587104273508,
          "source" : "https://localhost:8443/selfservice/menu/SELFSERVICE_MYINFO",
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGOUT",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [ ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**match login query on whole dataset**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "action.keyword": "LOGIN"
    }
  }
}
```

**response from above query**

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 5,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0033021,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ede971d5-d284-4205-96b0-6ee4cc441d83",
        "_score" : 1.0033021,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "ede971d5-d284-4205-96b0-6ee4cc441d83",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104355983,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser_09"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "d0ebf819-506a-493e-9b2e-a427073b038e",
        "_score" : 1.0033021,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "d0ebf819-506a-493e-9b2e-a427073b038e",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104270464,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser_09"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "a3a8bce5-f246-4c26-ba69-d2ca1917b650",
        "_score" : 1.0033021,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "a3a8bce5-f246-4c26-ba69-d2ca1917b650",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "3000",
          "principal" : "rootuser",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104280465,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "3000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "023079d8-b94c-4831-9135-0b75c6d423c2",
        "_score" : 1.0033021,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "023079d8-b94c-4831-9135-0b75c6d423c2",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
          "principal" : "rootuser_09",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104659807,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS",
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "ff8081816e87f4f8016e8d4aff6f0000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser_09"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "indexname",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "873816ad-7e46-4ffa-abf9-1ea5a0bcf04b",
        "_score" : 1.0033021,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "873816ad-7e46-4ffa-abf9-1ea5a0bcf04b",
          "entityType" : "indexname",
          "userId" : "3000",
          "principal" : "rootuser",
          "managedSysId" : "0",
          "timestamp" : 1587104336316,
          "source" : null,
          "clientIP" : "127.0.0.1",
          "nodeIP" : "username-Latitude",
          "action" : "LOGIN",
          "result" : "SUCCESS"
          "correlationId" : null,
          "customRecords" : [ ],
          "targets" : [
            {
              "targetId" : "3000",
              "targetType" : "USER",
              "objectPrincipal" : "rootuser"
            }
          ],
          "parentLogs" : [ ],
          "childLogs" : [ ],
          "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**It will be a great help. thank you so much**

Answer (score 0):

Collapse gets applied after query and post filter. So you cannot run a filter on collapsed fields

This can be done  in aggregation.

I have used [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html), [max aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html), [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) and [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html)

**Data**

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "index6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "T1n7jHEBF99yL6wFi1ji",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "userid" : 1,
          "timestamp" : "2020-04-18T00:00:00",
          "action" : "LOGIN"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "UFn7jHEBF99yL6wFtFhz",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "userid" : 1,
          "timestamp" : "2020-04-18T01:00:00",
          "action" : "LOGOUT"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "UVn7jHEBF99yL6wF21ia",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "userid" : 2,
          "timestamp" : "2020-04-18T00:00:00",
          "action" : "LOGIN"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "Uln7jHEBF99yL6wF8Fip",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "userid" : 2,
          "timestamp" : "2020-04-18T01:00:00",
          "action" : "LOGOUT"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index6",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "U1n8jHEBF99yL6wFFFh1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "userid" : 2,
          "timestamp" : "2020-04-18T02:00:00",
          "action" : "LOGIN"
        }
      }
    ]
```

User1 : last action logout
User2 : last action login

**Query:**

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "userid",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "last_visted_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "timestamp"
          }
        },
        "activity_login": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "action.keyword": "LOGIN"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "last_login_date": {
              "max": {
                "field": "timestamp"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "active_users":{
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "lastvisted":"last_visted_date",
              "lastlogindate":"activity_login>last_login_date"
            },
            "script": "if(params.lastvisted==params.lastlogindate){return true;}else{return false;}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Perform terms aggregation on user and find last login date and last visited date . If both are same return user

```
User1
     LastVistedDate: "2020-04-18T01:00:00"  
     LastLoginDate : "2020-04-18T00:00:00"
     Don't return since both are not same

User2
     LastVistedDate: "2020-04-18T02:00:00.000"  
     LastLoginDate : "2020-04-18T02:00:00.000"
     Return since both are not same
```

Result:

```
"users" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "activity_login" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "last_login_date" : {
              "value" : 1.5871752E12,
              "value_as_string" : "2020-04-18T02:00:00.000Z"
            }
          },
          "last_visted_date" : {
            "value" : 1.5871752E12,
            "value_as_string" : "2020-04-18T02:00:00.000Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, I had two doubts first `lastlogindate":"activity_login>last_login_date` * *why you used this since you already got each user max timestamp and each user max login timestamp, comparison can be done with both right * * ? just let me know. and one thing how to use this query inside kibana visualization it gives me error  `[parsing_exception] [size] query malformed, no start_object after query name` .

Comment: This was to filter out users who last activity is login. This is used in bucket selector aggregation. First we create buckets of users and find their last date and last login date. If both dates are same then we keep that bucket. If we don't do it we won't be able to know whether last activity was login or logout. Regarding kibana visualization, I don't have experience with it so can't help you there

Comment: I agree with the your comment, but the aggregation `last_login_date` is part of `activity_login` aggregation itself, and to compare two object we need same kind. I think comparison should be of `last_visted_date>last_login_date` correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Bucket path is way of accessing the buckets. You have to give full path to the bucket. In the end we are comparing last_visted_date with last_login_date. Since last_login_date is subaggregation under activity_login, it has to be mentioned in the path

Comment: Sorry I could not understood, thanks a lot  i got it now.

Comment: Please upvote and accept as answer if it resolved your issue

Comment: I am gonna update it but still waiting for kibana answer from someone.